# Indicating which thread when handler (timer) called?

Tags: c, multithreading, timer

I have multiple threads running (pthreads api), each with it's own timer that calls a function handler(int signum) after a certain interval. As these threads call handler and within the function handler, how do I know which thread called it? Is thread-specific data required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `pthread_self()` function to have the ID of the current thread.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to know is which thread is executing, [`pthread_self()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_self.html) to get your unique thread id should be all you need.

That said, not knowing your timer implementation, if you need more than an ID I'd simply have the pthread pass in an object from its own context as a parameter to the handler. That will allow you to pass in any data without resorting to [pthread_setspecific()/pthread_getspecific()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_setspecific.html)